# Updating a global variable from 2 different components simultaneously using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reactn

I have a global variable that is an array.

In 2 different components they add an element to the array simultaneously on mount. But in order to add an element to the array they need to clone the current one & add to it. Since they're mounting simultaneously, the array is empty when they clone it. So only one  element is added to the array.

How can I use useEffect to run the inserted code once on mount & run the return code on dismount reading a global variable that can change.

here's an example

store.js

```
import { setGlobal } from 'reactn';

const initStore = () => {
  setGlobal({
    globalArray: [],
  });
};

export default initStore;
```

component-number-one.js

```
import React,{useEffect, } from 'react';
// works just like useState but makes the variables accessible anywhere
import { useGlobal, } from 'reactn';
// Just a clone util, clones stuff
import { clone } from '../../../utils/clone';

const ComponentNumberOne = () => {

  const [globalArray, setGlobalArray] = useGlobal('globalArray'); 

  useEffect(() => {
    // Only want this to run on mount
    let newGlobalArray = clone(globalArray); // Problem is here, doesn't know globalArray has an updated value
    newGlobalArray.push("ComponentNumberOne");
    setGlobalArray(newGlobalArray);

    // Only want this to run on dismount
    return () => {
      let newGlobalArray = clone(globalArray);  // Possibly problem here too
      let index = newGlobalArray.indexOf("ComponentNumberOne");
      newGlobalArray.splice(index,1);
      setGlobalArray(newGlobalArray);
    }
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="ComponentNumberOne">
      ComponentNumberOne stuff
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentNumberOne;
```

component-number-two.js

```
import React,{useEffect, } from 'react';
// works just like useState but makes the variables accessible anywhere
import { useGlobal, } from 'reactn';
// Just a clone util, clones stuff
import { clone } from '../../../utils/clone';

const ComponentNumberTwo = () => {

  const [globalArray, setGlobalArray] = useGlobal('globalArray'); 

  useEffect(() => {
    // Only want this to run on mount
    let newGlobalArray = clone(globalArray); // Problem is here, doesn't know globalArray has an updated value
    newGlobalArray.push("ComponentNumberTwo");
    setGlobalArray(newGlobalArray);

    // Only want this to run on dismount
    return () => {
      let newGlobalArray = clone(globalArray); // Possibly problem here too
      let index = newGlobalArray.indexOf("ComponentNumberTwo");
      newGlobalArray.splice(index,1);
      setGlobalArray(newGlobalArray);
    }
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="ComponentNumberTwo">
      ComponentNumberOne stuff
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentNumberTwo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useEffect` should have `globalArray` in its dependencies array.

Of course, just putting `globalArray` in the dependencies breaks your code.

The *actual* problem is that your code behaves "imperatively", i.e. "if the component is mounted, add an item to the array. That is not the way React is supposed to be used.

Instead of telling React when to do something, you should tell React what state you expect. I.e. update the array to represent the desired state, e.g.:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    if( !globalArray.includes("ComponentNumberTwo") ){
      setGlobalArray([
        ...globalArray,
        "ComponentNumberTwo"
      ]);
    };

  }, [ globalArray ]);
```

Comment: I think I'll need to do something differently. The array is basically a queue of updates for a web socket. So on mount, it subscribes to a channel, and on dismount it unsubs. Problem is that the socket may not be open, which is why it loads into the queue first to wait for the socket to open. Thank you for this answers though.

Comment: You could move the "set state" logic out of the individual components to some central place, e.g. a [custom "useQueue" hook](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html). Or you could use [`context`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/). That way you could say e.g. `dispatch([ 'ADD_ITEM_TO_QUEUE', item ])`, without having to deal with the previous state inside the local components.